# Why does TextFormField let me input past maxLength?

Tags: flutter

I have a Form, and this is one of the fields:

```
Widget _title() {
    return TextFormField(
      maxLength: 60,
      maxLengthEnforced: true,
      minLines: 1,
      maxLines: 2,
      focusNode: _titleFocusNode,
      controller: _titleController,
      validator: (value) {
        if (value.length < 4) {
          return 'Title is too short (at least 3 characters)';
        }
        return null;
      },
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        labelText: "Title",
      ),
    );
  }
```

However, I am able to input past the MAX_TITLE_LENGTH:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Use `inputFormatters` property. The following code would limit the textFormField to 60 in length

Sometimes `maxLength` does't work as expected i am not sure why,instead of `maxLength` you can use `inputFormatters` it works every time without a glitch

**Import**

```
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
```

in TextField

```
new TextFormField(
  inputFormatters: [
    new LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(60),
  ],
);
```